# Raspberry Pi Serial Communication with Arduino with Python

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I want to communicate between my Raspberry Pi and Arduino using Python.
So far the Arduino successfully sends a serial message to the Raspberry Pi and the message is read with the **ser.readline()** function in Python.
But when I want to blink a led connected to my Raspberry Pi with an IF statement it won't work

The **blink()** function and everything else works but the code won't go into the IF statement that checks the **ser.readline()** value with a **string variable**

This is the code of my Arduino:

```
 String data="hello";

 void setup() {
 // put your setup code here, to run once:
 Serial.begin(9600);
 }

 void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 Serial.println(data);//data that is being Sent
 delay(5000);
 }
```

And this is the Python code which runs on my Raspberry Pi:

```
 import serial
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time

 LedPin = 11    # pin11
 ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)  #change ACM number as found from ls /dev/tty/ACM*
 ser.baudrate=9600
 def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)       # Set the board mode to numbers pins by physical location
    GPIO.setup(LedPin, GPIO.OUT)   # Set pin mode as output
    GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH) # Set pin to high(+3.3V) to off the led

 def blink():
            print 'led on'
            GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.LOW)   # led on
            time.sleep(1.0)                 # wait 1 sec
            print 'led off'
            GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH)  # led off
            time.sleep(1.0)                 # wait 1 sec


 setup()
 while True:
    serialmessage = ser.readline()
    print("serial message is " + serialmessage)

if serialmessage == "hello":
    print("message recieved")
    blink()
```

This is what I see in the terminal:
[image: terminal_image]

I've been searching for hours trying to find a solution but with no luck.
I've also just started programming in Python.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Might be a good idea to test with a standard serial terminal app on the Pi just to check the link is working

Comment: Assuming the indentation shown here accurately reflects your source, your `if` statement and call to `blink()` aren't inside the `while` loop. They need to be indented.

Answer (score 0):

```
import serial                                                                                          
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                                                                                
import time                                                                                            

LedPin = 11    # pin11                                                                                 
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)  #change ACM number as found from ls /dev/tty/ACM*              
ser.baudrate=9600                                                                                      
def setup():                                                                                           
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)       # Set the board mode to numbers pins by physical location            
   GPIO.setup(LedPin, GPIO.OUT)   # Set pin mode as output                                             
   GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH) # Set pin to high(+3.3V) to off the led                              

def blink():                                                                                           
           print 'led on'                                                                              
           GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.LOW)   # led on                                                    
           time.sleep(1.0)                 # wait 1 sec                                                
           print 'led off'                                                                             
           GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH)  # led off                                                   
           time.sleep(1.0)                 # wait 1 sec                                                


setup()                                                                                                
while True:                                                                                            
   serialmessage = ser.readline()                                                                      
   print("serial message is " + serialmessage)                                                         

   if serialmessage == "hello":                                                                        
       print("message recieved")                                                                       
       blink()
```

Python uses spacing to detect blocks of code.

You need to put an if statement with a call to the blink method inside a while loop.

Also you can check incoming serial data by running command on Raspberry pi

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```